# Populating a Plotly graph from a two lists

Tags: python, plotly

I'm try to create a simple bar graph from two lists inside a python script. However, when data is populated into the plotly system it shows no graph. Below is the code i've written, the contents of the lists and the code produced by Plotly. 
Perhaps this is a case of needing to split the lists in some way before populating the graph? Forgive me is this is a novice question, i've never tried this before. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Script Code:**

```
 mycount = Counter()
 mytime = []
 with open('temp_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
     readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
     incoming = []
     for row in readCSV2:
          readin = row[0]
          time = row[1]
          year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
          ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
          wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
          incoming.append([wkday,time])
          mycount[wkday] += 1
          mytime.append(time)
     with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
         writer = csv.writer(out_file)
         writer.writerows(incoming)
 csvfile2.close()

 os.remove('./temp_dates.csv')

 daysum = []
 daylist = []
 for key,value in sorted(mycount.iteritems()):
     mylist = key, value
     daysum.append(value)
     daylist.append(key)

 s = pd.to_datetime(mytime).to_series()
 timesum = s.groupby(pd.cut(s.dt.hour, bins=np.arange(26, step=2),                include_lowest=True)).size()
 print(timesum)

 print(daylist,daysum)

 data = [go.Bar(
             x=[(daylist)],
             y=[(daysum)]
     )]
 py.plot(data, filename='basic-bar'
```

**Contents of Lists:**

```
[0, 2]       2
(2, 4]       0
(4, 6]       9
(6, 8]      12
(8, 10]     12
(10, 12]     6
(12, 14]    15
(14, 16]     8
(16, 18]     4
(18, 20]     4
(20, 22]     3
(22, 24]     2
```

**Code created by Plotly:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')
trace1 = {
  "x": [
    ["Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday",     "Wednesday], 
  "y": [
    [13, 11, 7, 9, 12, 13, 1], 
  "type": "bar", 
  "xsrc":     "quantumspores:1:b909c3,e16d42,692b77,e11300,9392dd,055dcf,274160", 
  "ysrc":     "quantumspores:1:bfbdce,f9103e,b0f1e0,d226d3,0091a5,40646f,5d2d35"
}
data = Data([trace1])
fig = Figure(data=data)
plot_url = py.plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to plot the bar chart of each day?

```
 data = [go.Bar(
             x=[str(x) for x in daylist],
             y=[int(x) for x in daysum]
     )]
```

or plot the bar chart of each two days?

```
 data = [go.Bar(
             x=[str(x) for x in timesum.index],
             y=[int(x) for x in timesum]
     )]
```

whatever you choose, the go.Bar need x as the string, and y as the numeral.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks for the comment. That works for the second graph that I need to produce. Timesum will show number of requests by time of day (in 2hr increments). The first graph i'm trying to produce is a show is requests by day which requires daylist (days of the week) and daysum (# of requests per day).

Comment: Just saw your second post - let me give that a shot!